# Laravel middleware authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

Currently to add authentication I use this in my routes file:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
});
```

But I want to also check for different routes if the user is an admin, so currently I do this and have a custom middleware file:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->group(function () {
});
```

//

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Admin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
        {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('dashboard');

    }

}
```

This all works fine, but I noticed with the api middleware it uses this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

**Questions**

1. How can I make a namespaced auth middleware like the api one `'auth:admin'`
2. Where is the file located that sets the `'auth:api'` middleware, I could not find it anywhere in the app folder
3. Is there any other ways to do multiple auth like editing the file `config/auth.php` and then separating the users between two tables, one for admins and one for other users.

Answer (score 0):

`auth:api` is actually the basic `auth` middleware with the string `api` as a parameter. This means the user is [authenticated using the `api` authentication guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#via-middleware)

You could use `auth:admin` out of the box if you added [a custom authentication guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-guards) for the admins.

Answer (score 0):

The `auth` middleware accepts one parameters which is the guard(s) to use. As you can see in [`Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.html) middleware.

You can add [custom auth guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-guards). So you can create `auth:admin` if you'd like. But I do think it's perfectly fine to use one middleware to verify that the user is who he is (authentication) and a second one to verify that the user is allowed to visit the page he/she wants to visit (authorization).